The code is not returning anything just taking inputs again and again
I'm just making a name generator for practice. I've tried removing the input function but it still doesn't give any value. Its a small code:
import random
l = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','y','x','z']

name = []

ui = input()

if ui == 'gen':

    while len(name) != 4 or 5 or 6 or 7:
        name.append(random.choice(l))
name = ''.join(name)

print(name)

I wanted it to print a name that contains 4,5,6 or 7 letters. But it doesn't prints anything.

the reason of it doesn't prints anything. is because it never can get out of while len(name) != 4 or 5 or 6 or 7:, because you use or here, or 5 or 6 or 7 will always true. you can write like that: name_len = random.choice([4, 5, 6, 7]); while len(name) != name_len:

by the way, you can import string; random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) instead of input l='a'-'z' by hand.

I think that's high level for me as I don't understand what it does but I will catch up to it real soon! Thanks! @recnac

just keep studying day by day, you will be better.
